# How to use Filter with map in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

How do I use Filter with map in javascript in such a way that:
var arrIds = [1, 3, 4]
Menu.map only displays the values if the id's present in "arrIds array" matches with the ids present in "Menu".

```
import Menu from './data';
 {(arrIds && arrIds.length)? 
      (
        //filter
        Menu.filter().map(r => 
          <div className="card">   
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-2">
                  <Avatar className={classes.large} alt="Photosnap" src={r.logo} /> 
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                  <p>
                      <span className="m1">{r.company}</span>
                      {(r.new1===true)?(<span className="m2">NEW!</span>):""}
                      {(r.featured===true)?(<span className="m3">FEATURED</span>):""}
                  </p>
                  <p className="md">{r.position}</p>
    
                  <p className="ml">{r.postedAt} · {r.contract} · {r.location}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 rta">
                  <button value={r.id, r.role} id="myBtn" className="btn1" onClick={e => handleRole(e, "value")} key={r.id}>{r.role}</button>
                  <button value={r.id}  className="btn1" onClick={e => handleLevel(e, "value")} key={r.id} >{r.level}</button>
                  {r.languages.map((p) => <button value={ r.id, p} className="btn1" onClick={e => handleLanguages(r.id, p)} key={r.id}>{p}</button>)}
                  {r.tools.map((p) => <button value={r.id, p} className="btn1" onClick={e => handleTools(r.id, p)} key={r.id}>{p}</button>)}
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        )
      ):
      (
        Menu.map(({id, company, logo, new1, featured, position, role, level, postedAt, contract, location, languages, tools}) => 
      <div className="card">   
          <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-2">
                  <Avatar className={classes.large} alt="Photosnap" src={logo} /> 
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-4">
                  <p>
                      <span className="m1">{company}</span>
                      {(new1===true)?(<span className="m2">NEW!</span>):""}
                      {(featured===true)?(<span className="m3">FEATURED</span>):""}
                  </p>
                  <p className="md">{position}</p>
                  <p className="ml">{postedAt} · {contract} · {location}</p>
              </div>
              <div className="col-md-6 rta">
                  <button value={id} id="myBtn" className="btn1" onClick={e => handleRole(e, "value")} key={id}>{role}</button>
                  <button value={id}  className="btn1" onClick={e => handleLevel(e, "value")} key={id} >{level}</button>
                  {languages.map((p) => <button value={ id, p} className="btn1" onClick={e => handleLanguages(id, p)} key={id}>{p}</button>)}
                  {tools.map((p) => <button value={id, p} className="btn1" onClick={e => handleTools(id, p)} key={id}>{p}</button>)}
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      ))}
```

data.js file (Menu)  contains array of object:

```
export default [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "company": "Photosnap",
    "logo": Photosnap,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Senior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Senior",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["HTML", "CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "company": "Manage",
    "logo": manage,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": true,
    "position": "Fullstack Developer",
    "role": "Fullstack",
    "level": "Midweight",
    "postedAt": "1d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "Remote",
    "languages": ["Python"],
    "tools": ["React"]
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "company": "Account",
    "logo": account,
    "new1": true,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Junior",
    "postedAt": "2d ago",
    "contract": "Part Time",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["React", "Sass"]
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "company": "MyHome",
    "logo": myhome,
    "new1": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Junior Frontend Developer",
    "role": "Frontend",
    "level": "Junior",
    "postedAt": "5d ago",
    "contract": "Contract",
    "location": "USA Only",
    "languages": ["CSS", "JavaScript"],
    "tools": []
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "company": "Loop Studios",
    "logo": loopstudios,
    "new1": false,
    "featured": false,
    "position": "Software Engineer",
    "role": "FullStack",
    "level": "Midweight",
    "postedAt": "1w ago",
    "contract": "Full Time",
    "location": "Worldwide",
    "languages": ["JavaScript"],
    "tools": ["Ruby", "Sass"]
  }
]
```

**If the "id" value present inside each object in data.js(Menu) file === the array if ids present in "arrIds" then mapping as to take place.**

*If not filter with map in javascript, what else can I use?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can `filter` the menu items before `mapping` over them. You can use [`Array.prototype.includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes) to check if the menu item id exists in the `arrIds` array. If `arrIds` is falsy or is an empty array, you can return `true` to display all the menu items.

```
Menu.filter((item) =>
  arrIds?.length ? arrIds.includes(item.id) : true
).map((item) => {
  // ...
})
```